# How to control the HTML CakePHP creates

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cakephp

i'm working on an application built on the CakePHP framework and that uses AJAX (with jQuery).

I'm having troubles using the jQuery plugin "tablesorter" with AJAX-modified tables, since I think my View isn't producing the output it's supposed to : table structure in the actual HTML output isn't what my PHP code should do (missing tags, tags appearing from nowhere).

I'm new to CakePHP, so my question is :
**Is there a way to control how CakePHP modifies the HTML output ? Or -even better- to disable this annoying feature ?**

Maybe am i dreaming and maybe CakePHP isn't guilty for this one, but I never saw anything like that before (I used to code in PHP without framework).

PS : sorry for my english, french inside.

EDIT : 
here's the code in my view :

```
echo'<thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Dénomination</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
</thead>';
?>

    <?php foreach ($products as $product){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $product['Product']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($product['Product']['denomination'], '/products/view/'.$product['Product']['id'], array('escape'=>false)); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $product['Product']['quantity']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
     ?>

<script> 

    $("#result").tablesorter();
</script>
```

and here's the HTML output :

```
<table id="result">
    <tbody>
       <tr> <td>64</td>
            <td>

....
```

I don't think it's usefull to go any further since `<thead>` isn't there and `<tbody>` is.

Comment: Please show the code you have in your view and what the actual output is.

Comment: Bear in mind that cake doesn't modify the HTML output; it will output exactly what you tell it to.

Comment: here's the code in my view :
 <?php 
 
 echo'<thead>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Dénomination</th>
  <th>Stock</th>
 </thead>';
 ?>
 
  <?php foreach ($products as $product){ ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $product['Product']['id']; ?></td>
   <td>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link($product['Product']['denomination'], '/products/view/'.$product['Product']['id'], array('escape'=>false)); ?>
   </td>
   <td><?php echo $product['Product']['quantity']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php }
   ?>
  
 <script> 
  
  $("#result").tablesorter();
 </script>

Comment: and here's the output :
<table id="result">
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>64</td>
       <td><a href="#">...</a></td>

I don't think it's usefull to go any further since the <thead> isn't in the HTML and <tbody> is... which is not what my code is supposed to do.

Comment: what is the output without the tablesorter? just for sure...

Comment: @sipiatti : same :/ the problem is, how am I supposed to sort a table without <thead> Oo
I guess i'll have to change my code bit by bit to figure out what's wrong since according to Ross cake doesn't interfere with the output.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right view? The output isn't even close to what you have in the view.

Comment: Absolutely. The View is /app/view/products/search.ctp and the output is from the url '/products/search'

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your search.ctp file for viewing table.

```
<table id="result" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="emailTable display table" width="100%">
<thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Dénomination</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php 
    foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product['Product']['id']; ?></td>
            <td>

                <?php echo $this->Html->link($product['Product']['denomination'], '/products/view/'.$product['Product']['id'], array('escape'=>false)); ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $product['Product']['quantity']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
</tbody>
```

```
<script> 
$("#result").tablesorter();
</script>
```